# Is there a way to stop Visual Studio from automatically adding an Imports line when I select a method from the navigation bar?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to write some VB code that consumes a couple of webservices.  Whenever I select one of the methods from the navigation bar, Visual Studio insists on adding an Imports line at the top of the page.  This is very annoying, particularly as there are a couple of structures in each web service with the same name, but different signatures and, because VS has replaced the fully-qualified names when it added the Imports, I'm getting errors.

I've tried manually removing the Imports and re-qualifying all the entries VS has bodged, but it all gets undone if I reselect a web service method from the navigation bar.

I'd prefer VS to leave the fully-qualified object names and not add an Imports line!

Answer (score 0):

You could try an alias for the fully qualified name you wish to use.

```
Imports a = Fully.Qualified.Name
```

The in the code

```
a.MethodName
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I'd really rather not have the Imports at all.  We always prefer to use fully qualified references in code; that way code can be copied and pasted into other programs we write and we don't have VS complaining when we try to run it that it doesn't know what xxx is!

Answer (score 0):

In VS2022, go to Tools->Options->Text Editor->Visual Basic->Advanced and uncheck "Add missing Imports on Paste"